# Prove that, for all sets A, B and C, if A ⊆ C and B ⊆ C then A ∪ B ⊆ C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

First of all, I am sorry to ask this question on math.stackexchange.com but its very urgent/important. I have asked on other sites to this question before asking on math stackechange but no response. Tomorrow I have Discrete Math exam and I almost spend 3 hours to prove this but I don't know how can I prove it. Again the question is Prove that, for all sets A, B and C, if A ⊆ C and B ⊆ C then A ∪ B ⊆ C.

So far, I have tried : 
X ∈ P(A ∩ B) 
      iff X ⊆ A ∩ B 
      iff X ⊆ A and X ⊆ B... can't proceed.

Comment: Hint: Start with the assumption $x\in A\cup B$ and prove that $x \in C$.

Comment: All you have to do is to show that each element of $A\cup B$ is an element of $C$. I cannot see why you have brought $A\cap B$ into this.

Comment: Element chase should always be your first attempt.  If $x \in A\cup B$ then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.  If $x \in A$ then as $A\subset C$, $x \in C$.  And if $x \in B$ then as $B\subset C$, $x \in C$.  So either way $x \in C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$.

If $x\in A$, then since $A\subseteq C$, $x\in C$. 
If $x\in B$, then since $B\subseteq C$, $x\in C$.

Therefore, $A\cup B\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 2):

if A ⊆ C and B ⊆ C then A ∪ B ⊆ C

Proof: Let $x \epsilon AUB$

Then $x \epsilon A$ or $x \epsilon B$

Then $x \epsilon c$ or $x \epsilon C$ (by definition of subset)

Note that $pVp \implies p$

Then $x \epsilon C$

Then AUB ⊆ C (definition of subset)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x\in A$ or $x\in B \iff x \in A\cup B$.

We have $A\subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$, so for any $x\in A\cup B$, $x\in A$ or $x\in B$.  In either case, $x\in C$.